# How to resolve this design flaw?

Tags: c++, glew

Developing a game of teris I came to a conclusion that using usual MVC pattern would potentially clutter my code, as well as, because of how OpenGL is working under GLEW, make it substantially harder to build upon. Instead I came up with this neat modification, also reliant on Observer pattern, that would make somewhat more sense, at least in short term (image does not reflect complete class tree):
[image: makeshift architecture]

To explain: 
-Every box is a class, `Engine` holds instance of `Entities`, `Game` holds instances of `Figure`. 
-`Figure` inherits `Entity`. 
-`Engine` observes `Game`, and `Game` is coupled by observers with `Figures`.
How it should work: 
Ideally, I should instantiate `Engine` which will set GLEW and GLFW along with everything else that will make up the window, then create a `Game` object, which, in new thread, will create a figure, and notify the engine to start the drawing loop, and when that figure is set, pass it with an object pointer to `Engine` via Observer. 
This would work beautifully, I would be able to add all sorts of figures by inheriting `Entity`, figures wouldn't fall from the screen, as every coordinate update would go through `Game`, and I could, probably, give every figure a unique shader, if that would be necessary. 
How it actually works:
Engine is initialized, Game is initialized, Figure is called for in another thread, and throws

```
atioglxx.dll: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000728.
```

when asked to access any OpenGL function. 
I suspect this happens because the `Figure` doesn't know that all of the supporting functionality is launched in `Engine`. And I can't just do it again in `Figure`. I could move everything that has to do with View to the `Engine`, but then I would not be able to set separate shaders, and I would have to construct VAOs (Vertex Array Objects) for every figure inside `Engine`. 
So how do I make the error go away, while introducing as little changes as possible?

Comment: this may be an interesting problem, but may also be off-topic here.

Comment: @Walter, I considered placing it on gamedev.stack but it doesn't seem to be dealing as much with architectural problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that all OpenGL calls for a given context need to be on the same thread.  A longer answer is on the way...

---

First, `Entities` need to be able to draw themselves with GL calls.  You can't mix Drawing code from one thread with another, the OpenGL client state wouldn't be correct.  (Think of OpenGL as a 'C' state machine).

Second, you need to buffer the Entity states by frame.  The `Engine` may or may not be finished submitting draw calls when you start your next frame in the `Game` thread.  So you need some synchronized way to submit all `Entity` states for a frame.  This gets a little tricky because you want to avoid synchronization primitives (e.g. mutexes) that might stall your pipeline or cause blocking.

You can read the [Doom III source code](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3-BFG) which used a double buffered pipeline for submitting draw calls to the `Engine` backend.  The trick is that Doom does most everything on the main thread, then splits off to execute Draw Calls on the backend (`Engine`) thread and submit draw states (`Entities`) for the next frame on the `Game` main thread.  Then it waits on the `Engine` thread to finish and swaps the buffers.

Read up on Metal and Vulkan multithreading.  These are very similar.

Resources need to be loaded on the `Engine` and returned handles for your entities to reference ( Shaders, Textures, Static Geomety, etc..)